# Remove event listener from custom-elements

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element

Consider a simple custom element `simple-element` I cannot remove event listeners:

```js
const myElement = document.getElementById('myElement');

function removeListener(){
  // works
  this.style.backgroundColor = ''; 
  this.style.color = 'red';
  // NOT WORKING
  this.removeEventListener('click', handleEvent.bind(this));
  this.span.innerText = 'Event Listener "handleEvent" not removed, you can still click this "simple-element"'
}

function handleEvent(){
  this.style.backgroundColor = '#069';
  this.style.color = '#ffffff'
}

// sample custom element
(() => {
  class SimpleElement extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();

      this.template = document.createElement('template');
      this.template.innerHTML = 
`<style>span {color: inherit}</style>
<span>Simple element content<br>Click ME</span>`;

      // Patch shadow DOM
      if (window.ShadyCSS) {
        window.ShadyCSS.prepareTemplate(this.template, 'simple-element');
      }

      this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
      this.shadowRoot.appendChild(this.template.content.cloneNode(true));

      // Patch shadow DOM
      if (window.ShadyCSS) {
        window.ShadyCSS.styleElement(this)
      }
    }

    connectedCallback(){
      this.span = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('span');
      this.addEventListener('click', handleEvent.bind(this))
    }
  }

  customElements.define('simple-element', SimpleElement);
})();
```

```css
simple-element {padding: 1rem 0.25rem; width: 100%; display: block}
```

```html
<simple-element id="myElement"></simple-element>
<br>
<button onclick="removeListener.call(myElement)">Remove Listener</button>
```

No matter where / how I choose to define and execute the event listener removal, it won't work.

I appreciate any reply and thanks in advance.

Comment: `.bind()` returns a new function every time it is called and that is why i think event listener is not getting removed.

Comment: Does `.apply` have the same effect?

Comment: No, `call` and `apply` don't return a new function, `bind` returns a new function.

Comment: What do you suggest? `this.addEventListener('click', handleEvent.apply(this))` doesn't work.

Comment: `handleEvent.apply(this)` - this won't work because it will immediately call the function

Comment: I wrapped the `handleEvent` to all kinds of possible wrappers, I still can't remove the listener. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating dependencies all over.

If a Custom Element **adds** an EventListener, then that same Custom Element should handle its behaviour

```html
<my-element id=ELEMENT>
  <button id=BUTTON>Remove Listener</button>
</my-element>

<script>
  BUTTON.onclick = (evt) => ELEMENT.removeListener();
  
  customElements.define('my-element', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super() // sets and return this-Scope
        .attachShadow({mode: 'open'}) // sets and returns this.shadowRoot
        .innerHTML = `<style>:host{display:inline-block}</style>
                      <div>Simple element content<br>
                        Click ME <slot></slot>
                      </div>`;
      this.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick )
    }
    handleClick(evt) {
      this.style.background = 'teal';
      this.style.color = 'white';
    }
    removeListener() {
      this.style.background = 'none';
      this.style.color = 'red';
      this.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClick);
      this.shadowRoot.querySelector("div").innerText = `Event Listener "handleClick" removed`;
    }

  });
</script>
```

#### INLINE Events

Instead of `addEventListener` (which can add multiple events)
you can also use an **inline** Event (only one function possible)

Not only shorter notation, it makes it easier for your Component user to overwrite behaviour.

```
// assign
this.onclick = this.handleClick;
// remove
this.onclick = null;
```

Also note Events you assign to Elements are removed by the *JavaScript Garbage Collection process* when the Element is removed from the DOM. So you don't have to remove those Listeners yourself.

If your Elements adds Listeners to **other** Elements like `document` you **do** have to remove those,
in the `disconnectedCallback`

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I always try and make sure I don't pollute the global with listeners, that is why I was asking the question in the first place :). Cheers!